# Why doesn't github show jsx/tsx files?

Tags: github

This might be a trivial question but why isn't jsx and tsx on github's recognized languages list? Is it because they are simply extensions of js and ts? If so why don't they show up when you look for all javascript files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [jsx listed as one of the extension of Javascript](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/9edd34988273d307180a1bfc4dfa30a9f2f79105/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L2583-L2608) in the syntax highlighting GitHu  support of [`github/linguist`](https://github.com/github/linguist)

As [Reacts itself defines JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html):

> It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript.
> We recommend using it with React to describe what the UI should look like. JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with the full power of JavaScript.

So yes, those Javascript/Typescript extension are part of the same base language as far as GitHub search is concerned.